# Derivation of Erlang PDF from Pascal PMF

Tags: probability

The $k$-th arrival time in a Bernoulli process is the Pascal PMF of order $k$:
$$P_k(n) = {n-1 \choose k-1}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

As an experiment, I tried to derive the Erlang PDF of order $k$ from Pascal's. The motivation is following: a Poisson process can be approximated by a Bernoulli process with a large number of slots. Therefore, it should be possible to derive all properties of Poisson by taking the corresponding properties of Bernoulli and letting $n \to \infty$.

The result is almost right, but not quite: I have an extra $\frac yn$ term which makes the whole thing zero. Please help me spot the error. Does it even make sense? This is my derivation:

Let $\lambda y = np$ and let $n \to \infty$. Then, the Erlang PDF of order $k$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
f_k(y) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} {n-1 \choose k-1}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(k-1)!}\frac{(\lambda y)^k}{n^k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda y}n\right)^{n-k} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\cdot y\cdot\frac{\lambda^k y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\cdot\left(1-\frac{\lambda y}n\right)^n\cdot\left(1-\frac{\lambda y}n\right)^{-k} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\cdot y\cdot\frac{\lambda^k y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\cdot e^{-\lambda y}\cdot 1 \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac yn\cdot\frac{\lambda^k y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\lambda y} \\
&= 0 \\
&\ne \frac{\lambda^k y^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\lambda y}
\end{aligned}$$

To me, this part looks most suspicious, but at the same time trivial and correct:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$$ The reason is because there are $k-1$ elements in the numerator which when divided by $n$ tend to $1$.

Comment: Is what you call a "$k$-th arrival time in a Bernoulli process is the Pascal PDF" what I call a form of "negative binomial distribution"?

Comment: If you have $\lambda y = np$ and $n\to \infty$ then does this mean either $p \to 0$ or $\lambda \to \infty$ or $y \to \infty$?  It looks as if you are saying $p \to 0$.

Comment: I made a typo, it is 'Pascal PMF'. When $n\to\infty$ $p\to0$, while $\lambda$ and $y$ are constant.

Comment: Indeed it looks like a negative binomial distribution. I used the term 'Pascal PMF' as it was introduced in my textbook (Intro to Probability by Bersekas, Tsitsiklis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption  $f_k(y) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P_k(n)$ is not correct even when you state $p=\frac{\lambda y}{n}$, as it does not take account of the left-hand side being a density and the right-hand side being a probability.

In a slightly informal argument:

- $P_k(n)$ is equivalent to
- $\mathbb P(N\le n+\frac12) - \mathbb P(N\le n-\frac12)$, an interval of width $1$
- about $\mathbb P(Y\le y +\frac12\frac yn) - \mathbb P(Y\le  y-\frac12\frac yn)$, if you let $Y=\frac yn N$,
- which is $\int\limits_{y-\frac12\frac yn}^{y+\frac12\frac yn} f_k(u) \, du$ if this method works
- approximately $\frac yn f_k(y)$ since the integral is over an interval of width $\frac yn$.

In other words $f_k(y) \approx \frac ny P_k(n)$,

and what you should be looking at is $f_k(y) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac ny  P_k(n)$.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful